# Mongodb Aggregate Help syntax error

Tags: mongodb

I need help in this aggregate,

```
db.billingcycles.aggregate([{
$project:{credit:{$sum:”$credits.value”},debt:{$sum: “debts.value”}},
}, {
$group:{_id:null,credits:{$sum:”$credit”},debt:{$sum:”$debt”}}
}])
```

Error: 2017-10-13T00:23:16.375-0300 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):2:23

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
db.billingcycles.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        "credit": {
            $sum: ”$credits.value”
        },
        "debt": {
            $sum: "$debts.value"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": null,
        "credit": 1,
        "debt": 1
    }
}]
```